# Conditions for a modular multiplication graph to contain $k$-cycles

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, alternative-proof

Let the multiplication graph $n:m$ be the graph with points $0,\dots,m\text{ - } 1$ and a line between points $a$ and $b$ when $n\cdot a \equiv b\operatorname{mod} m$.

From the answers to two [other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3035966/explanation-of-an-unexpected-observation-in-modular-arithmetic) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3027415/cycle-structure-of-the-permutation-x-mapsto-p-x-operatornamemodq-for-coprim) I've learned why especially the multiplication graph $3:64$ has $4$-cycles, and that in general a multiplication graph $n:m$ has $k$-cycles iff $k = \operatorname{ord}_d(n)$ for some factor $d$ of $m$, with the [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) $\operatorname{ord}_d(n)$ being the smallest $p$ with $n^p \equiv 1 \operatorname{mod}d$ for coprime $n,d$.

My question is:

> Are there simpler necessary or sufficient conditions on $n$ and $m$
>   for $n:m$ having a $k$-cycle than by cumbersomely first finding the
>   divisors of $m$ and then calculating for each of them
>   $\operatorname{ord}_d(n)$?

This is, how the multiplication graphs containing $4$-cycles are distributed in the table of graphs for $n, m = 2,..,20$, $n < m$ (click the picture to enlarge):

[image]

Do you see a distribution pattern that could be exploited to get some simpler conditions?

Note that the smallest graphs with a $7$-cycle are $7:29$, $16:29$, $20:29$, $23:29$, $24:29$, $25:29$.